# Reading files using Apache Camel FTP location

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have a new requirement in Apache camel where I need to read a file from an FTP location which contains the file name another file in the same FTP location. 
So I need to read the first file get the file name and read the second file name. How do we achieve in Apache camel?

Comment: What have you tried to acheive this?

Comment: I tried below option but how to get filename2 from file1 is the question from("ftp://servername?"+"password=password"+"&antInclude=filename")
       .process(new Processor() {
                      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                          exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(),String.class);                          
                      }
                  })
       .from(ftp://servername?"+"password=password"+"&antInclude=filename_2")

Comment: I think you need to review the basics again. Route 1 should fetch the file, extract the body and set it in a exchange property or header and then call route 2 which looks in the location where you stored the body of the file and does the ftp fetch.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple FTP route that consumes the first file (that contains the target file name). Once this file is read, you can forward the content to a [route builder](http://camel.apache.org/routebuilder.html), where you build the other FTP route that will consume the target file.

You can make use of the [FTP component *include* option](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html) to specify the pattern of the files names to consume.

Comment: I tried below option but how to get the file name from the previous file. 
{ from("ftp://servername?"+"password=password"+"&antInclude=filename")
       .process(new Processor() {
                      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                          exchange.getIn().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody(),String.class);                          
                      }
                  })
       .from(ftp://servername?"+"password=password"+"&antInclude=filename_2")}